# problem with flutter doctor [Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.]

Tags: flutter

flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 93125766296e2c6c)
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Crash report written to C:\Users\khith\Desktop\flutter_01.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter may not be installed properly on your system. Try cleaning up all flutter installations, reinstall and try again. If the problem still persists, add your issue to their GitHub repository's issues page,  using the like given in the error message.